# How can I play music from my computer through my iPhone 5?

Tags: mac

I am using MacOSX Snow Leopard.How can I play music from my computer through my iPhone 5?

Answer (score 1):

You can share your iTunes library and then access it from your iOS device, after connecting it to your library. To do so, check your settings in iTunes according to this:
[image: iTunes Settings]

On your iOS-device under Preferences→Music check the settings for Home-Sharing on the bottom of the page.
[image: iOS Settings]